# Is there a way to exit a single loop, and exit all loops?

Tags: ada

I have 2 loops an inner loop and outer loop. In one case I want to just exit the inner loop to go to the outer loop and in the other I want to exit from the inner loop to the normal program (in other words from the inner loop I want to exit it and the outer loop and continue execution on the man program)

Does anyone know a way I can do these both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible thanks to named loops. Example:

```
Outer_Loop:
  loop
    -- first inner loop
    loop
      …

      -- exit the inner loop when a condition is met
      exit when Check_Condition();

      …
      end loop;

    -- second inner loop
    loop
      …

      -- exit the *outer* loop, in this example unconditionally
      exit Outer_Loop;

      -- or you can combine it with a condition
      exit Outer_Loop when Another_Condition_Met();

      …
      end loop;
    end loop Outer_Loop;

  -- execution will continue here after 'exit Outer_Loop;'
  …
```

Reference (for the '95 version of the language) can be found [here](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~andy/lrm95/05_07.htm).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have a question, why does only one of the end statements have the the loop name in it? While the others only have end loop

Comment: Because for a named loop the identifier must be repeat within `end loop` — http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~andy/lrm95/05_05.htm The inner loops are not named, hence no identifier after `end loop`.

Comment: Ohh ok, basically you only need to name the end statment when you name the loop and you didnt name the end statments for the inner loops because you did not name the inner loops.